# Snake game: how to check if the head collides with its own body

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, canvas, 2d-games

You may have played Snake, a game where you have to eat food to grow and you fail if you collide with the snake's body or certain obstacles. The first part was easy, but the latter seems impossible to achieve.

I have tried to make a `for` loop check if the last element of my snake array is colliding with its other parts. My condition was like this: if the `x` position of the last item in my array is bigger than any of the array items' `x` position, and smaller than their `x` position plus their width, and so on. That didn't work.

Here's my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200px" height="200px" style="border:1px solid black"/>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var yPos = 20;
var width = 15;
var variable = 1;
var currentDir = 1;
//var xPos = (width+5)*variable;
var xPos = 20;
var myArr = [{myX:xPos,myY:yPos},{myX:xPos,myY:yPos},{myX:xPos,myY:yPos}];
var downPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var rightPressed = false;
var first = [0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180];
var firstX = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
var firstY = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
var okayed = first[firstX];
var notOkayed = first[firstY];
var maths = myArr[myArr.length-1];
function drawFood() {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(okayed,notOkayed,15,15);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();    
}

function drawRectangle() {

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,200,200);
    drawFood();

    for(var i = 0;i<myArr.length;i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(myArr[i].myX,myArr[i].myY,width,15);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(drawRectangle);
}


setInterval("calledin()",100);
function calledin() {
    var secondX = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var secondY = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    var newobj = {myX:myArr[myArr.length-1].myX+20,myY:myArr[myArr.length-1].myY};
    var newobjTwo = {myX:myArr[myArr.length-1].myX,myY:myArr[myArr.length-1].myY+20};
    var newobjLeft = {myX:myArr[myArr.length-1].myX-20,myY:myArr[myArr.length-1].myY};
    var newobjUp = {myX:myArr[myArr.length-1].myX,myY:myArr[myArr.length-1].myY-20};
    var okayNewObj = {myX:myArr[1].myX - 20,myY:myArr[1].myY};


if(myArr[myArr.length-1].myX > 180 || myArr[myArr.length-1].myX < 0 || myArr[myArr.length-1].myY > 180 || myArr[myArr.length-1].myY < 0)
        {alert("Game Over");window.location.reload();}

    if(myArr[myArr.length-1].myX > okayed-5 && myArr[myArr.length-1].myX < okayed+20 && myArr[myArr.length-1].myY < notOkayed+20 &&
    myArr[myArr.length-1].myY > notOkayed-5) {
        okayed = first[secondX];
        notOkayed = first[secondY];
        myArr.unshift(okayNewObj);
    }

    if(currentDir == 1) {
    myArr.push(newobj);
    myArr.shift();}

    if(currentDir == 2) {
        myArr.push(newobjTwo);
        myArr.shift();
    }

    if(currentDir == 4) {
        myArr.push(newobjLeft);
        myArr.shift();
    }


    if(currentDir == 3) {
        myArr.push(newobjUp);
        myArr.shift();
    }

     for(var i = 0;i<myArr.length-2;i++) {
     if(myArr[myArr.length-1].myX > myArr[i].myX &&
     myArr[myArr.length-1].myX < myArr[i].myX + 15 && myArr[myArr.length-1].myY > myArr[i].myY && myArr[myArr.length-1].myY > myArr[i].myY + 15)
     {alert("Game over");window.location.reload();} 
 }

}


function downed(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==40) {if(currentDir != 3) {currentDir = 2;}}
    if(e.keyCode==38) {if(currentDir != 2) {currentDir = 3;}}
    if(e.keyCode==39) {if(currentDir != 4) {currentDir = 1;}}
    if(e.keyCode==37) {if(currentDir != 1) {currentDir = 4;}}

}

function upped(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 40) {downPressed = false;}
}
document.addEventListener("keydown",downed,false);
document.addEventListener("keyup",upped,false);

drawRectangle();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want the game to be over whenever the snake collides with its body

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: could you instead tell me what part of my question was wrong?

Comment: The question wasn't wrong. You haven't given us a chance to understand exactly what is wrong with your code (and not with what you're trying to achieve). What have you tried which has failed?

Comment: Which part of the code you posted tries to handle the collision? The code is hard to read without some explanation or comments.

Comment: Each time the snake moves, just compare the new location that the snake head tries to move to, with each segment of the snake body and if there is a match then you know a collision has occurred.

Comment: the same part that checks if the xPos of the snake is bigger than the canvas' width

Comment: i tried this but it didn't work: 
  for(var i = 0;i<myArr.length-2;i++) {
   if(myArr[myArr.length-1].myX > myArr[c].myX && myArr[myArr.length-1].myX < myArr[c].myX + 15 && myArr[myArr.length-1].myY > myArr[c].myY && myArr[myArr.length-1].myY > myArr[c].myY + 15)
   {alert("Game over");window.location.reload();} 

 }

Comment: Please add this code to the question rather than in a comment. Thanks for posting what you have tried.

Comment: I'd use `Array.prototype.any` for this - here's some pseudocode: `bodyCoordinates.any(coords => coords === headCoords)` (es6 arrow function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the snake is represented by an array called `snake` in which the head is at index `snake.length - 1`. We have to compare the position of the head against the positions of the body segments at indices `0` through `snake.length - 2`.

The following code sets `okay` to `false` if the snake head has collided with a body segment. Otherwise, `okay` remains `true`.

```
var head = snake[snake.length - 1],
    x = head.x,
    y = head.y,
    okay = true;           
for (var i = snake.length - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
  if (snake[i].x == x && snake[i].y == y) {
    okay = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Below is a snippet in which I have modified your code to clarify the game logic and to simplify many of the calculations.

Instead of working directly with canvas coordinates, I represent each position with the column index `x` and row index `y` of a virtual grid cell. This lets us calculate the neighboring grid positions by adding 1 or -1 to `x` or `y`. When it comes time to paint the canvas, we multiply the virtual coordinates by the cell size.

I have replaced most of your literal values with variables. For example, instead of setting the canvas dimensions to 200 by 200, we can do this:

```
canvas.width = numCols * cellSize;
canvas.height = numRows * cellSize;
```

This lets us change `numCols` and `numRows` in one place to resize the whole game grid. All the calculations work out because they evaluate variables instead of using literals.

I altered the key-event handling to recognize the key codes for the W-A-S-D keys in addition to the arrow keys. When the game is embedded in a long web page, as it is here, you'll probably want to use the W-A-S-D keys so that the page doesn't scroll up and down while you're playing.

```js
var canvas,
    ctx,
    currentDir,
    startX = 1,
    startY = 1,
    startSnakeLength = 3,
    snake,
    cellSize = 18,
    cellGap = 1,
    foodColor = '#a2302a',
    snakeBodyColor = '#2255a2',
    snakeHeadColor = '#0f266b',
    numRows = 10,
    numCols = 10,
    canvasWidth = numCols * cellSize,
    canvasHeight = numRows * cellSize;

var food = {};

function placeFood() {
  // Find a random location that isn't occupied by the snake.
  var okay = false;
  while (!okay) {
    food.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * numCols);
    food.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * numRows);
    okay = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; ++i) {
      if (snake[i].x == food.x && snake[i].y == food.y) {
        okay = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

function paintCell(x, y, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x * cellSize + cellGap,
               y * cellSize + cellGap,
               cellSize - cellGap,
               cellSize - cellGap);
}

function paintCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  paintCell(food.x, food.y, foodColor);
  var head = snake[snake.length - 1];
  paintCell(head.x, head.y, snakeHeadColor);
  for (var i = snake.length - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    paintCell(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, snakeBodyColor);
  }
}
  
function updateGame() {
  var head = snake[snake.length - 1],
      x = head.x,
      y = head.y;

  // Move the snake.
  var tail = snake.shift();
  switch (currentDir) {
    case 'up': 
      snake.push(head = { x: x, y: y - 1 });
      break;
    case 'right': 
      snake.push(head = { x: x + 1, y: y });
      break;
    case 'down': 
      snake.push(head = { x: x, y: y + 1 });
      break;
    case 'left': 
      snake.push(head = { x: x - 1, y: y });
      break;
  }
  paintCanvas();
  x = head.x;
  y = head.y;

  // Check for wall collision.
  if (x < 0 || x >= numCols || y < 0 || y >= numRows) {
    stopGame('wall collision');
    return;
  }

  // Check for snake head colliding with snake body.
  for (var i = snake.length - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (snake[i].x == x && snake[i].y == y) {
      stopGame('self-collision');
      return;
    }
  }

  // Check for food.
  if (x == food.x && y == food.y) {
    placeFood();
    snake.unshift(tail);
    setMessage(snake.length + ' segments');
  }
}

var dirToKeyCode = {  // Codes for arrow keys and W-A-S-D.
      up: [38, 87],
      right: [39, 68],
      down: [40, 83],
      left: [37, 65]
    },
    keyCodeToDir = {};  // Fill this from dirToKeyCode on page load.

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  if (keyCode in keyCodeToDir) {
    currentDir = keyCodeToDir[keyCode];
  }
}

function setMessage(s) {
  document.getElementById('messageBox').innerHTML = s;
}

function startGame() {
  currentDir = 'right';
  snake = new Array(startSnakeLength);
  snake[snake.length - 1] = { x: startX, y: startY };
  for (var i = snake.length - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    snake[i] = { x: snake[i + 1].x, y: snake[i + 1].y + 1 };
  }
  placeFood();
  paintCanvas();
  setMessage('');
  gameInterval = setInterval(updateGame, 200);
  startGameButton.disabled = true;
}

function stopGame(message) {
  setMessage(message + '<br> ended with ' + snake.length + ' segments');
  clearInterval(gameInterval);
  startGameButton.disabled = false;
}

var gameInterval,
    startGameButton;

window.onload = function () {
  canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = numCols * cellSize;
  canvas.height = numRows * cellSize;
  Object.keys(dirToKeyCode).forEach(function (dir) {
    dirToKeyCode[dir].forEach(function (keyCode) {
      keyCodeToDir[keyCode] = dir;
    })
  });
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
  startGameButton = document.getElementById('startGameButton');
  startGameButton.onclick = startGame;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#gameCanvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#startGameButton, #messageBox {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#messageBox {
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>

<button id="startGameButton">Start game</button>

<div id="messageBox"></div>
```